# Future.delayed method not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-future

I want to perform a method after a delay in flutter, and I came across Future.delayed method, but the method was being called immediately without a delay.

I tried the following:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), method());
```

Comment: You are not passing in `method` here, you are calling `method()` and passing in the result of that method call. Parenthesis `()` after a method name calls the method.

Comment: replace `method()` with `method`

Comment: Thanks! I removed the () and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should increase the duration because 300 milliseconds is 0.3 seconds so you won't notice the delay, try 3000s instead

Comment: I tried bigger values and it was not the problem.